# OpenCMS production practices

Tags: eclipse, cvs, opencms

I'm (very) new to OpenCMS, and so is everyone else on my team.

We've just started a new project and we're using OpenCMS. Right now we have an instance of OpenCMS running on each developer's machine, as well as a production server.  We're using Eclipse/CVS for source control, but propagating changes to a different machine does not propagate the metadata OpenCMS stores for each file (obviously).

My coworker is looking for a script solution to import/export the metadata.  When the site goes live we'll set up a nightly commit of the content files into source control to grab whatever changes the marketing department has made.

This seems backwards to me.  Should we each have OpenCMS on our machines?  If so, how do other people get around the issue of getting the OpenCMS metadata into source control?  If not, what is the "normal" production practices for this situation?

Comment: How does OpenCMS keep its' "MetaData"?

Comment: It's stored in OpenCMS's database.  We could set up scripts to move it, but it seems like something OpenCMS should be able to do for itself.

Comment: OpenCms supports WebDAV. You can use that in combination with your IDE and CVS. What do you mean by 'meta data' exactly? The jsp templates?

Comment: @Mathias Lin: I'm looking into WebDAV now, thank you.  :)  I'm referring to the OpenCMS file type, as well as the properties (Title, Description, Keywords, NavText, etc etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, WebDAV is a good way. There also seems to exist a Maven plugin targeting team work.

The OpenCms mailing list is quite helpful in general for questions around OpenCms:

http://old.nabble.com/OpenCMS-Development-in-a-team-td28432519.html#a28432519

Here's the wiki entry about OpenCms + WebDAV

http://opencms-wiki.org/WebDAV_access_to_the_OpenCms_VFS